# How to Set Value in Formik from custom component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, formik

i have made custom component from react native picker and want to update value in formik when i change it but it say undefined variable setFieldValue when i pass it in my custom component prop as callback function how can i set formik value from my custom component below is my custom compoment which i have imported in formik page

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{
          calltype: '',
          callfrom: '',
          callto: '',
          calldate: '',
          joinedby: [],
          tripinfo: {},
          additionalinfo: '',
          autoaccept: null,
        }}
        // validationSchema={CallValidationSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting, resetForm}) => {
          setSubmitting(false);
          sendValues(values);
        }}>
        {({
          submitForm,
          handleBlur,
          touched,
          errors,
          values,
          handleChange,
        }) => (
          <View>
            <ARow
              row
              justifyContent="space-between"
              alignItems={'flex-end'}>
              <ACol col={6}>
                <Picker
                  callbeck={getdata}
                  fieldname="calltype"
                  data={pickerdata}
                  inputBgColor="#F5F5F5"
                  heading="Call Type"
                  placeholder={'Select Call Type'}
                  onerror={false}
                  color={'#A9A9A9'}
                  value={values.calltype}
                />
                {errors.calltype && touched.calltype ? (
                  <AText color={'red'} pb={'5px'}>
                    {errors.calltype}
                  </AText>
                ) : null}
              </ACol>
              <ACol col={6}>
                <AText xtrasmall right>
                  #1100669
                </AText>
              </ACol>
            </ARow>
         </View>
        )}
      </Formik>

const CustomPicker = ({
<Picker
      style={{
        color: color ?? '#0D4D8D',
        margin: -16,
        height: 68,
        marginRight: -12,
        marginLeft: -4,
      }}
      selectedValue={selected}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
        callbeck(fieldname, itemValue);
        setSelected(itemValue);
      }}>
      <Picker.Item style={{fontSize: 12}} value="" label={placeholder} />
      {!isEmpty(data) &&
        data.map(item => (
          <Picker.Item
            style={{fontSize: 12}}
            label={item.name}
            value={item.id}
          />
        ))}
    </Picker>
);
};
```

Comment: Where are you changing the value can you show?

Comment: ok i added custom component where i try to change formik state value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Issue is Solved i have not destructured formik properly thats why its saying undefined variable setFieldValue,now when i send setFieldValue function in prop it works..